# How do I to align this bar correctly?

Tags: css

I have this bar on omglolwtf.net in my firefox browser it shows great but in other browser such as safari on my iphone its out of place can someone please help me fix it.

Comment: Post your CSS for the bar.  Most likely it's an implementation difference between the platforms.  Try googling to see if there's any workarounds for different platforms.

Comment: tell more details of your code, js or html

Answer (score 1):

The bar simply use `position:fixed;` which is not recognized on several mobile device.
http://cubiq.org/what-you-can-really-do-with-native-position-fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some fall-back styles for mobile browsers. Sometimes you doesn't really need fixed bars on mobile web from the point of usability.

Additionaly, you said nothing about other desctop browsers. If you are preparing the markup you should try it in all the modern browsers. It not only helps you to recognize potential problems, but same time you can learn more about the technics prefered for crossbrowser styles.